# How to create JavaScript object with properties conditionally

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating an object as following in my Angular Controller.
However, I need to make `Password` and `Confirm Password` properties conditionally.

I am currently doing it in an `if/else` statement. If the condition is true execute the following code else execute the same code without `password` and `confirm_password` properties.

I found that it is repetition of code. Is there nicer way I can mention properties conditionally inside the object?

```
$scope.newStudentForm = {
rules: {
firstname: {
    required: true
},
lastname: {
    required: true
},
email: {
    required: true,
    email: true
},
password: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 6
},
confirm_password: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 6,
    equalTo: "#password"
},
student_role: "required"
},
```

Comment: Why can't you just set `required: false,` ?

Comment: use ternary opertator `'key' : (condition) ? 'value when condition satisfied' : 'value when condition failed' `

Comment: @strikers, thanks this is also nice way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `$scope.newStudentForm` without the required properties. then added the on condition

```
$scope.newStudentForm = {
    rules: {
    }
};
if(condition){
    $scope.newStudentForm.rules.password = {
        required: true,
        minlength: 6
    };
    $scope.newStudentForm.rules.confirm_password = {
        required: true,
        minlength: 6,
        equalTo: "#password"
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am trying it out. Once work, i shall mark your answer as Accepts. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the way [Satpal showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30589483/157247), but if you *really* want to, it is possible to do this within the object initializer, but it's a bit complex: You use spread to spread out either `undefined` or an object with `isProtected`:

```
$scope.newStudentForm = {
    rules: {
        ...(condition
            ?  {
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6
                },
                confirm_password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    equalTo: "#password"
                }
            }
            : undefined
         )
    }
};
```

Live Example:

```js
function example(condition) {
    return {
        rules: {
            ...(condition
                ?  {
                    password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 6
                    },
                    confirm_password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 6,
                        equalTo: "#password"
                    }
                }
                : undefined
             )
        }
    };
}

console.log("Condition false:");
console.log(example(false));
console.log("Condition true:");
console.log(example(true));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```