# Create object's property only in particular case

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to create a property for my object based on data retrieved from backend, but only if it exists.

```
const newItem = {
    isProtected = items.hasOwnProperty('PATHID') ? items['PATHID'] : undefined
}
```

In case, `items` does not contain the property `PATHID`, I wish not to create "isProtected" property. I can't figure it out if it's possible, instead I use "undefined" or "null" value.

Is there any way to not create property if it does not fulfill the assigned condition?

Comment: A conditional spread? `const newItem = { ...(items.hasOwnProperty('PATHID') ? { isProtected: items['PATHID'] } : {}) }`

Comment: @spender - LOL, I just [posted that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72302791/157247) on the earlier question, since it wasn't there, and came back to point the OP at it. :-D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder TIL: spreading `undefined` is a NOP. 

Comment: @spender - Yup! :-) `null` too.